# SQL Select Query with joins executing slow

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization

I have a `newsfeed` where users can `add posts`. I also have got communities which uses the same database table with non-community posts. The following query `selects data` added from the communities where I am a member and also public posts, but it executes really slow. Can you assist?

```sql
SELECT NF.postID,NF.userID,NF.url,NF.post,NF.context,NF.topic,NF.style,NF.type,NF.kind,NF.placeID,NF.audience,NF.itemID,NF.updated,NF.added,NF.expiry
FROM newsfeed NF
WHERE placeID IN (SELECT cmtyID
                  FROM cmty_members
                  WHERE userID = '$ini'
                  AND role !='pending'
                  AND role !='removed')
OR (placeID = '0' AND type = 'feed')
ORDER BY postID DESC
```

I tried Inner joins but didn't produce the desired output

```sql
CREATE TABLE `cmty_members`
    (`mid` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `cmtyID` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `role` enum('member','admin','moderator','removed','pending') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'member',
     `notifs` enum('enabled','disabled','','') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'disabled',
     `sortpostsby` enum('new_posts','top_posts','newest_activity','') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'new_posts',
     `added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
    )
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;


CREATE TABLE `newsfeed`
    (`postID` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `token` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
     `url` text NOT NULL,
     `post` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
     `context` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
     `topic` text NOT NULL,
     `style` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
     `type` enum('feed','moment','removed','pending') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'feed',
     `kind` enum('shared-post','duel-campaign','self-deleting','moment','profile','poll','games','repost','boost','cmtyInvite','cmtyDP','cmtyCDP') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
     `placeID` int(11) NOT NULL,   `audience` enum('public','friends') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'public',
     `canReply` enum('everyone','friends','nobody') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'everyone',
     `itemID` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `updated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
     `added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
     `expiry` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
    )
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci;
```

Comment: Without create tables and explain nobody can help

Comment: Please post the table- and index definition that are relevant here. Side tip: The SQL-injection wrt the `$ini` parameter can be spotted from space on a clear day.

Comment: MySQL is very poor at optimizing `WHERE column IN (<subquery>)`. Use `INNER JOIN` instead.

Comment: It's also bad at optimizing `OR` conditions. Split it unto two queries and use `UNION` to combine them.

Comment: @Barmar can you show me an example query

Comment: @nbk I'm lost, what do you mean

Comment: Can you please show the `join`s you tried? This also seems unrelated to PHP/mysqli.

Comment: @TINASHECHIMOMBO Do you have any indices on your tables?

Answer (score 0):

The code I once tried

```
$sql = "SELECT NF.postID,NF.userID,NF.url,NF.post,NF.context,NF.topic,NF.style,NF.type,NF.kind,NF.placeID,NF.audience,NF.itemID,NF.updated,NF.added,NF.expiry 
FROM newsfeed NF 
JOIN cmty_members ON cmty_members.cmtyID = NF.placeID 
WHERE cmty_members.userID = '{$ini}' 

UNION 

(SELECT NF.postID,NF.userID,NF.url,NF.post,NF.context,NF.topic,NF.style,NF.type,NF.kind,NF.placeID,NF.audience,NF.itemID,NF.updated,NF.added,NF.expiry 
FROM newsfeed NF 
WHERE placeID = '0' AND type = 'feed' AND audience = 'public') 
ORDER BY postID DESC";
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your script is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even if [you are escaping variables, its not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string%5D)! You should always use [prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either MYSQLI or PDO instead of concatenating variables into the query.

Comment: Did this code work? If not, it should be in the question, not an answer.